# Will my CRI CRI twin engine plane fly if I replace the engine with a single 15hp gasoline engine?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, aircraft-systems, airplane, homebuilt

I'm using a lighter materials to rebuild plane, to cut down plane weight to 56kg and a 1.2m 3blades propeller.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation Stack Exchange.  Please, take the [tour] and read through the [FAQ] to better understand how this Stack Exchange site works, and how to make this question better.

Comment: Are you asking about only having one engine on one side? That seems like a very bad idea...

Answer (score 3):

With half the horsepower of the original, it will fly, but just barely, even allowing for a bit more thrust efficiency using a larger slower turning propeller.  Your airplane may be 15 kg lighter, but the pilot's carcass is as much or more as a share of the total weight.

So figure on maybe, at best, 55 percent of the original's available thrust with a better prop, which like with most light twins, removes probably 70-80% of the thrust available for climb.  The original could climb 1300 fpm, so the 15 hp version might manage 300-500 fpm, depending on how hot and high you were and how heavy the pilot is. Gain a little weight from excess beer and your climb margin might disappear completely if the weather is hot and you have a fun 3-wheel go-kart.

In any case, you wouldn't get me in a 15 hp Cri-Cri.

Answer (score 0):

Having flown paramotors with around 15hp on tap, you may find that a max rate of climb in the tens of feet per minute might be ok on paper but it makes for an awful flying experience.